# ZF2 use a model from outside of project

Tags: php, cron, zend-framework2

I have a ZF2 model under a module and I want to call functions in this model from a plain PHP file. This file is located outside of the project folder.

Is there any way?

Comment: Impossible to answer without any code; the module classes that you use will need to be included/autoloaded, just as you would with any class. If the 'model' however represents a data object that connects with the a database (e.g Zend\DB) then you would also need to provided the connection, which would normally be configured and bootstrapped as part of a ZF2 application.